# How to create a context-free grammar for a role-playing game

Tags: java, grammar, interpreter, context-free-grammar

I am attempting to create a program that can compute strings of dice rolls (using the *n*d*n* format, so 2d8 would be rolling two 8-sided dice and summing them). I am working in Java, but that doesn't matter for this question. I don't have a lot of experience with context-free grammars and I have a few questions regarding how to create one.

I know the elements (tokens) I need are:

- Numbers
- Addition operators (+, -)
- Multiplication operators (*, /)
- the "dice" operator (d)
- the roll modifiers(kh, kl, dh, dl)

The roll modifiers are:

- kh:  keeping the highest *n* the dice. 4d6kh1 will keep the highest roll, 4d6kh2 will keep the two highest rolls, and so on.
- kl: keep highest *n* dice
- dh: drop highest *n* dice
- dl: drop lowest *n* dice

These modifiers are two characters each, preceded by a dice operator sequence (number d number) and followed by a number (the number of rolls to keep).

Possible inputs could be:

- 4d4
- 3d6 + 2d4
- 2 * (1d6+8)
- 4 * 1d20 + 2
- 2d20dl1
- 4d20kh2 + 3d8

My attempt at creating a grammar (EBNF):

```
expr = term (addop factor)*
term = factor (mulop factor)*
diceop = <number> 'd' <number>
dicemod = diceop dmod <number>
factor = <number> | ( expr ) | diceop
dmod = kl | kh | dl | dh
addop = + | -
mulop = * | /
```

where `<number>` is any number

I have a few questions about this:

1. Is this done/ordered in a way possible to implement?
2. how do I specify that in `dicemod` the number has to be less than or equal to the first number in the `diceop` term? Do I just do that in the code?
3. do I need a rule above `expr` (meaning the first token in any input is an `expr` type) or do I need something above that?

If it helps, this is how I have my classes for the AST package laid out as of now:

```
[abstract class] Node, extended by:
    [abstract class] Expr, extended by:
         [class] Number (0-9)
         [class] BinOp (+, -, *, /)
    [class] DiceOp (Number 'd' Number)
    [class] DiceMod (dl, dh, kl, kh)
```

Where `DiceOp` has to be preceded by a `Number` token and followed by a `Number` token; and `DiceMod` has to be preceded by a `DiceOp` token and followed by a `Number` token that is <= the first `Number` token held by the `DiceOp` token (as a child of the token).

I'm new to grammars and interpreters in general so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see a production defined for the nonterminal `dicemod` but I don't see another production that introduces that nonterminal. In other words, as it is currently written, your grammar is equivalent to one without `dicemod` at all. As to your second question: you can specify this in a CFG but only by creating a combined nonterminal for `diceop` and `dicemod` so the production(s) for that nonterminal can guarantee the relationship is maintained.

Comment: @Patrick87: A CFG cannot represent the language `n.m` where `n` and `m` are representations of numbers such that `n < m` (or, for that matter, `n = m`) unless the representation is unary. It is certainly not possible for decimal numbers.

Comment: @rici Yeah I thought about this some more and realize you're right. The problem is numbers of the same length right? The digit that breaks the tie could be anywhere.

Comment: @Patrick87. Yeah. You can do `n` is shorter than `m`, which is why unary numbers would be OK, but you can't do equality; only equality reversed. (So if OP could live with having to write one of the numbers backwards, it would be possible. But that's not a very user-friendly format.)

Comment: @Patrick87 could I include `dicemod` as a `factor`, or would that mess up `expr` and `term`? For the second question, could I just solve it in code by having the program tell the user that the input is invalid because the first number is larger than the second?